# convert raw aws s3 xlsx data to json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm, xlsx

I have an xlsx file in aws S3, i want to retrive it and convert to json.

I have tried many xlsx to json converters but they all seem to need the file path and wont work with raw file data.
I am able to convert to wb and get ws but then the ws data contains lots of unicode that is unable to be passed to json.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
util.s3_getObject(bucketName, fileName, true, false).then(data => {
    var wb = XLSX.read(data.data, {type:"buffer"});
    var ws;
    var target_sheet = "Sheet1";
    try {
        ws = wb.Sheets[target_sheet];
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ws)));
        console.log(wb.SheetNames);
        if(!ws) {
            console.error("Sheet " + target_sheet + " cannot be found");
            process.exit(3);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("error parsing "+fileName+" "+target_sheet+": " + e);
    }
    console.log("converting sheet to json");

    data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ws)));
    console.log("xlsx to json complete");
});
```

Is there away to remove the unicode or is there a better xlsx converter that will help with using the raw data from s3.getObject?

```
error parsing input/xls/test.xlsx Sheet1: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
var wb = XLSX.read(data.data, {type:"buffer"});
var ws;
var target_sheet = "Sheet1";
try {
    console.log("converting xlsx");
    ws = wb.Sheets[target_sheet];
    if(!ws) {
        console.error("Sheet " + target_sheet + " cannot be found");
        process.exit(3);
    }
} catch(e) {
    console.error("error parsing "+fileName+" "+target_sheet+": " + e);
    process.exit(4);
}
console.log("converting sheet to json");
data = JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have manage to get the worksheet. You can use XLSX library (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). You can try following snippet.

```
var obj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(worksheet);
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried that but i still get weird data. eg [{
 "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\�뾽\more_data....: "[\u0001����/��U\u0000�(more_data...."
},

Comment: What kind of data you get?

Comment: [{
 "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\�뾽\more_data....: "[\u0001����/��U\u0000�(more_data...."
},